# Convert list of numbers to list of length 1 byte objects

Tags: python, struct, byte, packing

I'm attempting to convert a list of numbers into a list of byte objects of length 1 for use with `struct.pack_into`. However, much to my surprise, I appear to be getting `n` 0s in each byte object:

```
>>> [bytes(n) for n in [1,2,3]]
[b'\x00', b'\x00\x00', b'\x00\x00\x00']
```

I was expecting:

```
[b'\x01', b'\x02', b'\x03']
```

How can I get the latter?

Comment: Apparently in your code do: `[bytes([n]) for n in [1,2,3]]`

Comment: Yep, got it. Thanks!